# Python: What does a trailing divide or slash symbol signify?

Tags: python, scapy

I am new to python and am trying to understand what the significance of trailing slashes means in the language. Specifically I am working with the Scapy library and am trying to decipher the get_rsn_information method in Scapy's [inject.py](https://github.com/securestate/eapeak/blob/master/lib/eapeak/inject.py) source file:

```
def get_rsn_information(self, essid):
rsnInfo = None
sendp(
    RadioTap()/
    Dot11(addr1=self.bssid, addr2=self.source_mac, addr3=self.bssid, SC=self.__fixSC__(), subtype=4)/
    Dot11ProbeReq()/
    Dot11Elt(ID=0, info=essid)/
    Dot11Elt(ID=1, info='\x82\x84\x0b\x16\x24\x30\x48\x6c')/
    Dot11Elt(ID=50, info='\x0c\x12\x18\x60'),
    iface=self.interface,
    verbose=False
)
<...snip...>
```

When I see a line that looks like this:

```
RadioTap()/
```

What does the trailing slash signify?

Comment: it means the line is continued on the next line, in this case i would expect a syntax error however, or maybe just division since it is enclosed in parentheses

Comment: It's legal in the call list; no syntax error.

Comment: It separates the layers of the packet.

Comment: the `/` operator is overloaded. You can see the code here https://sourcecodebrowser.com/scapy/1.0.2/classscapy_1_1_packet.html#ad356ffbd896ca3532f72dc1eb038a59a

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RadioTap`, `Dot11` etc are instances of `scapy.packet.Packet`. Its division operation is [overloaded](https://github.com/levigross/Scapy/blob/master/scapy/packet.py#L262) to stack packet layers.

I.e. syntactically this is exactly what it looks like, a division operator

```
#/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/packet.py
# source code like below:
class Packet(six.with_metaclass(Packet_metaclass, BasePacket,
                                _CanvasDumpExtended)):
...
    def __div__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Packet):
            cloneA = self.copy()
            cloneB = other.copy()
            cloneA.add_payload(cloneB)
            return cloneA
        elif isinstance(other, (bytes, str)):
            return self / conf.raw_layer(load=other)
        else:
            return other.__rdiv__(self)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

`sendp()` is a function with three arguments/inputs

the first input is

```
RadioTap()/Dot11()/Dot11ProbeReq()/Dot11Elt()/Dot11Elt()/Dot11Elt()
```

which means exactly what it says:

```
RadioTap() divided by Dot11() divided by....etc.
```

you're able to assume that because the open parenthesis after `sendp(` doesn't close and has no interruption until the comma before `,iface`

the other two inputs are `iface` and `verbose`